# Invalid Geometry in PostGIS but Valid in FGDB

Tags: postgis, geometry, file-geodatabase, invalid-data

I have a data with lots of polygons which illustrated below (and it's a little tip of my study area)
[image]

When I worked with ArcGIS, I run 'repair geometry' and it fixed some of the errors. Then, I uploaded the data to PostGIS using OGR2OGR command.

occasionally it gives wrong data (what I meant by wrong data is not showing but showing another time) so I checked geometry validity in PGadmin and it gives me an error.
[image]

so basically, it is not error in ArcMap FGDB but it is error in PostGIS.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you select the same geometry as WKT from a) fgdb and b) PostGIS to make sure that the conversion did not change anything? I believe that you can do that with ogrinfo `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select geometry from my_layer where objectid=13028" my.fgdb`.

Comment: it didn't change anything. hmm...

Comment: Add couple of features as WKT so we can evaluate in which way they are suspicious.

Comment: or? Is there an option in OGR2OGR to repair geometry when importing data to PostGIS?

Comment: In theory with the SQLite SQL dialect you could have a try with `-sql "select MakeValid(geometry) as geometry, attribute_1, attribute_2 from my_layer". The problem is to get a SpatiaLite version that supports MakeValid https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html because it is a new feature and its implementation is still changing (uses RTTOPO instead of LWGEOM in the development now). Why not to convert first and run ST_MakeValid in PostGIS afterwards?

Comment: do you know python? check out my question and the answer on importing feature class into postgis https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260372/python-psycopg2-insert-table-into-postgis-geometry-requires-more-points/260455#260455

Comment: i did fix the issue. please following this link. Thanks all for the helps! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264533/is-there-an-option-in-ogr2ogr-to-repair-geometry-when-importing-data-to-postgis

Answer (score 2):

We have had plenty of data that used to live in ArcGIS that when brought to PostGIS started throwing errors.

Fixing the data led us to this SQL, which shows exactly where the errors were:

```
select 

ST_IsValidDetail(geom)
, ST_IsValidReason(geom)
from "polygon_table"
where ST_IsValid(geom) = 'f'
```