# Is there an option in OGR2OGR to repair geometry when importing data to PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, ogr2ogr

this is related to one of my questions here [Invalid Geometry in PostGIS but Valid in FGDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264521/invalid-geometry-in-postgis-but-valid-in-fgdb)

If I could, I want to repair geometry while I am importing my data to PostGIS.
So I wrote this code below on OSgeo4W Shell

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=test password=test" D:\FGDB_Edit\OCEAN.gdb -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=shape -t_srs EPSG:3857 -nln ocean_repair -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(Shape) as geometry, * from ocean_boundary"
```

and it gives me this error
[image]

have you experienced this before? and have any solutions?

Comment: I believe the problem is that ST_MakeValid(shape) as geometry is being interpreted as shape -- hence column "shape" specified more than once -- despite the geometry alias. Try replacing * with a select list without the geometry column -- you don't need the invalid one anyway.

Answer (score 2):

so basically your whole code will be like this

> ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost
>   port=5432 dbname=yourdb user=yourid password=pw" inputGDBpath -lco
>   GEOMETRY_NAME=shape -t_srs EPSG:3857 -nln whatever_the_layer_name
>   -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(shape) as geometry, OBJECTID_1, objectid, sc1class_c, sc2class_c, sc3class_c, sc4class_c,
>   Shape_Leng, polygon_id, feature_type, display_id, language_code, name,
>   display_class, coverage_indicator, iso_country_code, ver_cnt, region,
>   nccode, bk_nccode, id, scalerank, featurecla, Shape_Length, Shape_Area
>   from ocean_boundary"

OBJECTID_1, objectid, sc1class_c, sc2class_c, sc3class_c, sc4class_c, Shape_Leng, polygon_id, feature_type, display_id, language_code, name, display_class, coverage_indicator, iso_country_code, ver_cnt, region, nccode, bk_nccode, id, scalerank, featurecla, Shape_Length, Shape_Area
these are the field in my feature class except "shape" field